# Glue ML tranform ---java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Unrecognized scheme null; expected s3, s3n, or s3a

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am working in ML transform in Glue .. I have a redshift table source which I successfully crawled and table created. I created a ML transform on this table and set the Label ID.

When I estimate the quality of the transform I get the below error. There is no custom code or anything to trouble shoot as this is standard functionality in Glue.. Not sure if any jar etc is missing.

Instead of provided the quality of the estimate I get the below error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Unrecognized scheme null; expected s3, s3n, or s3a

Comment: Can you edit your script and try adding redshiftTmpDir to your connection options as explained in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-redshift.html ?

Comment: Thanks Prabhakar.. I noticed that My redshift Cluster has only readonly permissions to S3... Please note what I am trying to do is run ML transform on schema created from a Redshift table..I am doing Estimate quality in ML transform which has no custom code associated with it..  Per documentation , I am thinking regardless the way Glue works with Redshift is via Rad and write access to S3.. Is my understanding correct? should the role permission to Cluster fix the issue?

Comment: The error that your job reported has nothing to do with S3 permissions. It looks Glue ML transform was looking for S3 scheme which means that it only support S3 sources. So I have asked to modify the autogenerated script to see if the argument redshiftTmpDir present

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs. But there is no autogenerated script yet. This is part of ML transform in GLue(sub section in glue).. Autogenerated script is part of Glue job..Your suspicion is correct as I do not get the error if I supply the same data from S3. So the only workaround is to load Redshift data to S3 and run the ML transform with S3 as source. thoughts?